# Add passes to passbook via custom iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios6, barcode-scanner, passbook

I need to get capture image of real world pass(loyalty card) from Camera or library (UIImagepickerviewcontroller) and add relavent field(like card name/card number) and need to save this IOS 6 's passbook. Please Suggest me,I am new with passbook functionality.

Or

Can we generate .pkpass file programmatically with IOS 6?

Answer (score 0):

You need a server to sign passes. See [Passbook for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/passbook/).

You can setup an API endpoint that responds to your app request with a `.pkpass` file, generated by the given fiedls and values.